# Why is my Custom User Meta deleted on Profile Update?

Tags: user-meta

I have problems with my custom user fields on updating the user profile withing the `/wp-admin/user-edit.php`. The values of the `huna` and `ki` field are deleted. The `validation` and `altUserID` still show up correctly. Where is my error in the code? Thanks for your help!

**Before Updating the User**

[image]

**After Updating the User**

[image]

**My Code**

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Magic Link", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="Secret">Secret</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="secret" id="secret" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'huna', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="Key">Key</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'ki', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="Validation">Validation</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="validation" id="validation" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'validation', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="Validation">Welcome Screen</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="welcome" id="welcome" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'welcome', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <h3>Misc</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="altID">Alternate ID</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="altUserID" id="altUserID" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'altUserID', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'huna', $_POST['huna'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'ki', $_POST['ki'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'validation', $_POST['validation'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'welcome', $_POST['welcome'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'altUserID', $_POST['altUserID'] );
}
```

Comment: You just need to use the correct input names in both your HTML and PHP. So if the HTML uses `name="secret"`, then the PHP would use `$_POST['secret']` - and not `$_POST['huna']`.

Comment: Ah, ok. There it is. Thanks for your help!